# How to create a hash from a enumerable?

Tags: ruby

How can I create a big hash automatically and store it in a file?

The result should be like :  `=> {:1=>10, :2=>10, :3=>10, ... :100=>10}`

Comment: How big of a hash?  All values = 10?  Store it in a file how? as a string?

Comment: the hash has to have one hundred pairs. with the keys form 1 to 100 and the values always 10. I dont know how to store it in a file. It must be something easily readable by a ruby code.

Comment: Slight digression: is `:1` a legal symbol? Do the keys *need* to be symbols?

Comment: What do you want the file to look like?

Comment: I dont know very well how the file should look like. But it shall be something easy to be red by a ruby code.

Comment: What do you intend to DO with the file? Just store values? Allow the file to be edited so it can be read in later and the program will work with the new values? Does the file have to be readable by humans or only code? Are other languages, such as Python, Perl, Java supposed to be able to understand the data? As is your question leaves a lot of unknowns so we can't give you a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that like this:

```
File.open('filename.txt', 'w') do |file| 
   file.write(Hash[(1..100).map { |i| [i, 10] }]) 
end
```

Comment: thanks @spickermann , it will do the work while I fiigure out the file thing

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us nearly enough to give specific recommendations, but, in general, you should look into using YAML to serialize the hash. [YAML is a defined specification](http://yaml.org) that makes it easy to store the data in a format easily read by people, and easily reused by other languages.

For instance, this is what a basic hash looks like when serialized:

```
require 'yaml'

hash = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
puts hash.to_yaml
```

Running that code will output:

```
---
a: 1
b: 2
```

Because it's just a string being output, it's easy to write it to a file:

```
File.write('hash.yaml', hash.to_yaml)
```

Which, when run creates a file in my current directory containing the above output:

```
$ cat hash.yaml
---
a: 1
b: 2
```

I can reread the data and parse it back into a hash just as easily:

```
hash = YAML.load_file('hash.yaml')
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```

I can modify the YAML file:

```
---
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
```

and reload it and see the new element:

```
hash = YAML.load_file('hash.yaml')
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

YAML is capable of serializing very complex arrays and hashes, and other languages can reuse that data. Objects get funky so it's always good to create your own `to_a` or `to_h` or `to_yaml` methods which then output an array or hash so the YAML engine can correctly serialize them.

Ruby's [YAML class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/index.html) only defines some of the methods. [Psych](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/index.html) is the underlying engine so its documentation is important also. For instance, I used `load_file` to reload the file, and it's documented in the [Psych documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_file).

Comment: omg! I am trying all this YAML thing and this is making all works perfectly. If I could upvote you 100 times I would do :)

Comment: Well, it's possible to change the selected answer, which you should do if this is what is your selected path.

Comment: well. I have used both. The first answer was a good one and helped me in the first part of the question "How can I create a big hash automatically...". And then you have helped my in the second part "...and store it in a file?". I can't select both saddly, and he was first. But believe me, your answer is in my heart next to the marked one.